# JS - how to remove image with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I faced a problem as to remove image with JS
code like a...

```
<img src="image.png" id='image_X'>
...
document.getElementById('image_X').src=''
```

Image stays unchanged :( So my question is how to remove image with JS?
To be more detailed... How to modify the image src attribute value dynamically?

Any useful comment is appreciated

Comment: Why not just remove the img tag completely?

Comment: I don't want to delete the tag itself, I need it

Comment: And, as a most better thing, I'd like to have something like document.getEelementById('image_X').src=null but I am not sure how to do that :)

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder whether your question above is descriptive enough to actually allow someone to provide an answer for what you are trying do in the bigger picture. Please try to provide more information about the approach you are using that includes the image tag's src element being empty/null.

Comment: document.getElementById('image_X').src='' work.
ahah, getEelementById, did you mean => getElementById without the getE(e)lementById

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var image_x = document.getElementById('image_X');
image_x.parentNode.removeChild(image_x);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5DdyL/

Comment: Hmm... Shall it remove "img" tag itself? I mean can the "image_X" object be reused then?

Comment: Yes, that would remove the element from the DOM. If you want to reuse the element (redisplay or move it somewhere else), you could hide it like in Xion's answer, or copy the url to a variable for later access, I suppose.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to remove the element from the DOM. I want to keep it there but at the same time to have its "src" attribute equal to "null" by clicking a button or something. Is it possible?

Comment: Why? What would be the point of an element you can't see with no src attribute?

Comment: No exactly so... I want to have src attribute on its place and at the same time I just want to have the src attribute to be "empty" or "not empty" by clicking a button. That's why I asked the question... Is it possible?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what you're up to. If you set the image's DOM element `.src` attribute to `''`, it will be empty. See: http://jsfiddle.net/5DdyL/1/ Note, you will need to have either Firebug or the Chrome console open to see the results.

Comment: But it is keeps on the web page? Can it be a double buffered problem?

Comment: Yeah, when the image is "cached" the code like document.getEelementById('image_X').src=null doesn't work :( Can it be the reason?

Comment: OK, I used "uncached" image for code document.getEelementById('image_X').src=null and it worked :) So the thing is I have to use non-cached images only to have them replaced?

Comment: Working perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

You could just hide it. In vanilla JS that would be:

```
document.getElementById("image_X").style.display='none';
```

In jQuery:

```
$("#image_X").css('display', 'none');
```

If you really want to remove it from DOM, there is `removeChild` method you could invoke on the `parentNode` of your image element.

Comment: I guess in a way that counts as "removing from view".

Comment: this is more idiomatic jQuery: `$("#image_X").hide();`

Comment: As I may guess, the code is hiding image but I'd like to have its src=null or something :( Is it possible to control img attributes values in such a way?

Comment: `$("#image_X").attr("src", "");`, but I'm not entirely sure there isn't a browser that will just show "invalid" placeholder (i.e. an 'x') if the `src` argument is empty. Better to hide/remove the whole image element.

Comment: It's great but I want to change img src from null to image.png for example :) For some reason code like a document.getEelementById('image_X').src=null doesn't work :( The image is not getting "empty" :( But I need to have it empty. How can I do that?

Comment: adding to what @Xion wrote, `$("#image_X").attr("src", "").hide();` should set src=null & hide it. then, `$("#image_X").attr("src", "image.png").show();` should restore the image

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
var el = document.getElementById('image_X');
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxJQu/)

You can neatly wrap that into a function like so:

```
function removeElement(ele) {
    ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
}

removeElement(document.getElementById("image_X"));
```

Comment: Hmm... I am not sure would the code do thing I want because I am interested to control the img content I mean just to remove its src content but not to remove the whole tag... So how to get the result?

Answer (score 3):

Gets its parent and use removeChild.

```
var parent = getElementById('parentid');
var child = document.getElementById('imagex');
parent.removeChild(child);
```

Comment: Emm... What the parent means in my case? I want to control the src attribute of tag <img src="image.png" id='image_X'>. How can I do that?

Comment: @user592704 Its whatever element the image is in... (ex. div, p, table, tr, td etc.) Just give that element an id, and replace parentid with that id!

Answer (score 2):

To delete an image in JavaScript (or generally to delete anything), first you should grab the element, then traverse to its parent element, then you can delete the child using `removeChild` method.

Comment: I don't want to remove tag itself but to have its src empty or something. So I need to get tags attributes and their values control but how?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

`document.getElementByID("").style.visibilty="hidden";`

when you do not want to show the image and

`document.getElementById("").style.visibility="visible";`

when you want to show the image.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share some additional tips...

@Marecky, Thank to Jared Farrish answer I could figure out some helpful points concerning JS...

But next I had to make my own additional research as well... It is not a super fact, but a little theory tip... So, as a result, I could find that browsers, as a any desktop app, of course, are created with some kind of GUI framework... As a rule, most GUI (for example Swing) frameworks, of course, may using double buffered objects to display graphics... So when it (FF for example) re-translates script to graphic objects the GUI sync rules come to life...

...OK... Coming from GUI re-painting problems to scripting itself...

So my question was about playing around DOM objects... The fact was the img tag doesn't update UI event if the code like document.getEelementById('image_X').src='' is activated; So the `<body>` tag space (for some reason) , I am not sure but, is keeping some kind of 'cached' state... And maybe that makes img (if it is in body) become 'static'; So I had to find some helpful additional object which supports dynamic UI update. As a test, I used div instead of the pure body tag to keep img in it; So not to update body but div inner content only and that helped. So using JS + HTML in my case was helpful...

I hope the tip saves ones day

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 document.getEelementById('image_X').src="''";
```

but it will display a broken image

Answer (score 0):

1) remove img element using parent node.
2) Then, Store that parent node.
3) Then, create new img element in that parent node.